# Getting items with LINQ sometimes doesn't work

Tags: vb.net, linq, lambda, predicate

I am very new to VB, please help me what's wrong with my code, I have no more idea how to reach the goal, that is:
In a ComboBox.selectedIndexChange method, I am getting a custom Control (DrawTree) with LINQ from a TabPage, then with Predicate delegate, I am getting the current CategorySet, because it's entries needs to be reset with the DrawTree's entries.
Extract from code:

```
Private Sub category_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles pool4Combo.SelectedIndexChanged, pool8Combo.SelectedIndexChanged, Pool16Combo.SelectedIndexChanged, Pool32Combo.SelectedIndexChanged
        Dim selectedCombo As ComboBox = sender
        If Not selectedCombo.SelectedIndex = -1 Then
            Dim selectedCategorySet As CategorySet = selectedCombo.SelectedItem
            Dim holder As TabPage = selectedCombo.Parent

            Dim drawTrees = From controls In holder.Controls.OfType(Of DrawTree)
                            Select controls
            Dim drawTree As DrawTree = CType(drawTrees(0), DrawTree)
            Dim pool As PoolSet = CType(context.Pools.Find(Function(n) (n.PoolName.Equals(holder.Name))), PoolSet)
            Dim cat As CategorySet = CType(pool.Categories.Find(Function(n) (n.CategoryName.Equals(selectedCategorySet.CategoryName))), CategorySet)
            cat.Entries = drawTree.getEntries()

            While holder.Controls.Count > 1
                holder.Controls.RemoveAt(holder.Controls.Count - 1)
            End While
            etc.
            etc.
            etc.
        End If
    End Sub
```

So, the problem is, when this code runs `drawTree.getEntries()` will be `Nothing`, however, if I comment out `pool` and `cat` declarations, and just printing out `drawTree.getEntries()`, it will contain the entries I need.
Why is that and how to solve it?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Those two lines that set `drawTrees` and `drawTree` should collapse to `Dim drawTree = holder.Controls.OfType(Of DrawTree)().First()`. If there will never be more than one then use `Single` instead of `First`.

Comment: There's nothing obvious in your code that explains your issue.  You need to debug the code properly.  If `drawTree.getEntries()` returns `Nothing` with the two preceding lines in place and not without them then something in those two lines is affecting the data that you expect to be retrieved by that method. Debugging properly will show you what that is.

Comment: Thx, I modified `drawtree` declaration. I'm debugging a lot, but can't solve this. It was a try for something bigger (save the previous combobox selections), now I know, the problems start when I add this single line: `Dim drawTree = holder.Controls.OfType(Of DrawTree)().Single()` In this drawtree there are the previous combobox data, so I really need it. Without this, I can't save the previous state, with this, the current drawTree won't appear. Should I edit the code to show the whole? Many thanks jmcilhinney, I saw lots of your solutions, soon I'll write a new question based on one of it.

Comment: OK, thanks to that mentioned debugging, I realised that there were two `drawTrees` in the result and I was dealing with the wrong one :/